# Install app to program files instead to user profile dir using ClickOnce

Tags: winforms, clickonce

Can a WinForms exe be installed to program files instead of the user profile dir?

I can have the app installed once in the program files and later all updates should go in the same location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following thread should answer your question.

[How to control the location of ClickOnce installation?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/84b5ed72-2406-4518-97e7-f7c6cf7132a7)

> ClickOnce applications are installed per user in the user
>   application cache. These applications
>   are managed by the ClickOnce service.
>   If you want to install to a user
>   specified location such as C:\Program
>   files\ ... you should use MSI or some
>   other installer technology.

More about ClickOnce on MSDN:

[ClickOnce Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28VS.90%29.aspx) (See the ClickOnce and Windows Installer Comparison Table)